# I'm having trouble with a map reduce script

Tags: mapreduce, typeerror, netsuite

I'm creating my first map reduce script. I'm running an item search in the get input stage that outputs:

{
"recordType": "assemblyitem",
"id": "XXXXX",
"values": {
"internalid.memberItem": {
"value": "XXX",
"text": "XXX"
},
**"itemid.memberitem": "Member Item is displayed here",**
"type.memberitem": {
"value": "InvtPart",
"text": "Inventory Item"
},
"memberquantity.memberitem": "",
"itemid": "Assembly",
"type": {
"value": "Assembly",
"text": "Assembly/Bill of Materials"
},
"quantityonhand": "",
"quantitycommitted": "",
"quantityonorder": "25",
"quantitybackordered": "34",
"reorderpoint": "4",
"preferredstocklevel": "6",
"memberof": "",
"memberquantity": "60",
"memberbaseunit": "",
"quantityonhand.memberItem": "9509",
"quantitycommitted.memberItem": "3656",
"quantityonorder.memberItem": "",
"quantitybackordered.memberItem": ""
}
}

to the map stage. There I parsed the JSON as "var searchResult" and I'm creating a variable:

var memberItem = searchResult.values.itemid.memberitem;

The issue is I cant figure out is why it is throwing an error "TypeError: Cannot read property "memberItem" from undefined" on every result even though "itemid.memberitem" key and value is in every result set.

Any ideas? Thanks

I've spent hours trying to figure this out but with no success. trial and error is time consuming since I have to execute the script each time I try something else. At this point I'm out of ideas.

Comment: show the script. Your problem is most likely with the value of the parsed JSON. Which simply contains something else, not an object corresponding to the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, try to use: `var memberItem = searchResult.values['itemid.memberitem'];`

If you format your JSON:

```
{
    "recordType": "assemblyitem",
    "id": "XXXXX",
    "values": {
        "internalid.memberItem": {
            "value": "XXX",
            "text": "XXX"
        },
        "itemid.memberitem": "Member Item is displayed here",
        "type.memberitem": {
            "value": "InvtPart",
            "text": "Inventory Item"
        },
        "memberquantity.memberitem": "",
        "itemid": "Assembly",
        "type": {
            "value": "Assembly",
            "text": "Assembly/Bill of Materials"
        },
        "quantityonhand": "",
        "quantitycommitted": "",
        "quantityonorder": "25",
        "quantitybackordered": "34",
        "reorderpoint": "4",
        "preferredstocklevel": "6",
        "memberof": "",
        "memberquantity": "60",
        "memberbaseunit": "",
        "quantityonhand.memberItem": "9509",
        "quantitycommitted.memberItem": "3656",
        "quantityonorder.memberItem": "",
        "quantitybackordered.memberItem": ""
    }
}
```

you'll see, that you have a property named `itemid.memberitem` in the values object, which looks like a search join.

On the other hand you do have an `itemid` property there, which is a string, and it shouldn't be `undefined`, in your JSON it's `'Assembly'`, so not sure if this will help.

Comment: Thanks d.k, You are correct in that it is a search join column. all the other variables in "values" works fine. But, it doesn't seem to like adding the joins "internalid.memberitem", "itemid.memberitem", or "type.memberitem" after the "values". Sorry about the formatting. (Mine looked like yours except the grey background up until it was posted). I will give your suggestion a try.

Comment: Unfortunately, your suggested change had no effect. getting the same error.

Comment: Small update, through trial and error, I returned to the original "var memberItem = searchResult.values.itemid.memberitem;" and it no longer throws the typeerror, but it also returns nothing even though they all have values....Strange. Maybe its a Netsuite bug...

Comment: I asked you to show the script. W/o seeing it it's simply not worth to guess: too many possible reasons exist

Comment: No more relevant code beyond what I already shared. "Function (map)" > parse JSON as "searchResult". > assigning variables based on the keys in searchResult. I already shared an example of the parsed JSON that the get input stage is passing to the map function.  "var memberIid = searchResult.values.itemid;" works as expected. My best guess is that the map process is confused over the key having a "." in its name , so it is expecting another set of data under "itemid" called "memberitem{}". I appreciate the attempt all the same. Your guess is better than anything I had left to try.

Comment: Just had a thought, Today, I will try to figure out how to change the key names in searchResult JSON of the join fields to something else without the "." in the name before assigning the variables. Solution sounds solid in theory. Or at least to test if I'm right about that being the issue. Even better to just strip the "."out of the key name should do it.. (itemid.memberitem > itemidmemberitem). Just have to learn how to do that if possible.

Comment: Update: Renaming the joined field keys by removing the "." in the key names fixed the issue. Apparently the Map/Reduce Map function does not like Netsuite joined fields in the searches due to how it names the joined keys. This may help others down the road.